# How to save data when changing views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I hope an easy question (but I can't solve it :)) I have 2 views, On view 1 I have UILabels that I change the text on with a button click, if I navigate to view 2 and then go back to view 1 the text is reset.

Is there any way to retain the text on the label when the view is changed?

Originally I used:

```
-(IBAction) napButton: 
(id) sender{ nap *nap1 = [[nap alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 
[self presentModalViewController:nap1 animated:YES];
```

this performed a simple view switch. With the suggestion below I changed this to:

```
-(IBAction) napButton: 
(id) sender{ nap *nap1 = [[nap alloc] initWithNibName:@"nap" bundle:nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nap1]; 
[nap1 release]; } }
```

The button performs no action and I get warning `UINavigationController may not respond to -pushViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In a memory constrained device this is the best way to push or pop new views while preserving data or state in previous view.

An instance of `UINavigationController` can be created either in code or in an XIB file with relative ease. It’s thought of as a stack: it has a root view controller, and then new view controllers can be pushed onto the stack (often when the user taps on a row in a table) or popped off the stack (often by pressing the back button).

There are 4our methods are used to navigate user through the stack:

```
– pushViewController:animated:
– popViewControllerAnimated:
– popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
– popToViewController:animated:
```

For example if you want to move from view1 to view2, you need to do this from view1 -

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView];
    [secondView release];
```

to move back to the previous state, i.e. from view2 to view1, you need to do this from view2 -

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This should solve your problem in the most efficient way.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still seeing issues, I have a button on the view to make the change, originally I used:  -(IBAction) napButton: (id) sender{
nap *nap1 = [[nap alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:nap1 animated:YES]; with your suggestion I changed this to:   -(IBAction) napButton: (id) sender{
   nap *nap1 = [[nap alloc] initWithNibName:@"nap" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:nap1];
   [nap1 release];
  }
} The button performs no action and I get warning UINavigationController may not respond to -pushViewController

Comment: Sorry the explanation above may not be the clearest but with the code used:-(IBAction) napButton: (id) sender{ nap *nap1 = [[nap alloc] initWithNibName:@"nap" bundle:nil]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:nap1]; [nap1 release]; } The button now has no action and warning warning UINavigationController may not respond to -pushViewController is given.